# Passing parameter to unix shell script called from Python

Tags: python, shell

I need to pass a file through my Linux shell script which is being called from Python.

I tried the below command, but it does not pass the parameter:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("sh split.sh PathtoActualInputFile=" + fileslocation,
                           shell=True)
```

Comment: Is `sh split.sh PathtoActualInputFile=/path/to/some/file` how you would actually call the program from the command line? That's the string passed to the shell by your `Popen` object.

Comment: Are you trying to pass an argument to the shell command, or set an environment variable?

Comment: Also, I point you at the warning about using `shell=True` in `subprocess` calls - https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: @pcurry `fileslocation = "./some_file_that_exists; rm -rf $HOME/"`? =) *Just for the record to the curious people, do not run this, please.*

Comment: @luk32 Yeah, that's the danger.

Comment: @luk32; it'd probably be better in general to stick a non-destructive or less-destructive command in there, like `rm -ivf $HOME/` or `echo rm -rf /home`, and then say something about "imagine if that didn't have the 'echo'" or something like that.